# How to alter values in a column for a large number of data in MySQL? Can it only be done manually for each value or is there another way?

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I am having a column value as:

```
code    value
#125    abc
#137    xyz
#197    pqr
```

And I want to change (Remove first character? Remove all # Signs?) values as:

```
code    value
125    abc
137    xyz
197    pqr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean to remove the first character?

```
UPDATE t SET c = SUBSTRING(c, 2)
```

Or remove leading hashes?

```
UPDATE t SET c = TRIM(LEADING '#' FROM c)
```